# How to use replace() as adding '.' between the numbers?

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, if my number is 5899, I want to insert a decimal point between the numbers to get the result of 58.99. I know `(num/100).toFixed(2)` would work, but just wondering if there is a way for using replace.

Answer (score 7):

A regular expression can look ahead for 2 digits followed by the end of the string...

```js
console.log(
  String(5899).replace(
    /(?=\d{2}$)/,
    '.'
  )
);
```

but `.toFixed` makes a lot more intuitive sense, and so should probably be preferred.